# Modify select join to use one query instead of two

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Please consider the following query:

```
SELECT item.*, address_book.Country
FROM item 
INNER JOIN address_book
ON item.addressbook_id=address_book.idaddress_book and address_book.Country="USA"  order by rand() limit 100;  ;
```

What I would normally do after that is If I get no results to run another query without any restrictions on the country (so that I will get all the countries).

If I get results but they are less than 100 I then rerun the second query for all the countries but with a limit (100-myexistingnoofresults)

Is there any way to use only the first query and modify it somehow so the first x results to be USA (per the example) and the rest anything  and if no results for "USA" exist to display anything else.

Also if possible I would like to display the results randomly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `order by` in a slightly tricky way to achieve this. I think you can also use `Rand()` to order randomly, but it's not something I've tried.

```
Select
    item.*, 
    address_book.Country 
From
    item 
        Inner Join
    address_book 
        on item.addressbook_id = address_book.idaddress_book
Order By
    Case When address_book.Country = "USA" Then 0 Else 1 End,
    Rand()
limit 100;
```

Comment: very clever so when the country is USA this is a 0 otherwise it is a 1 then it just orders the results by case so 0s first right? Is it possible to also order the first set of results (USA) randomly every time?

Comment: @Athanatos I've added something that might order it randomly.